# Blender to 3ds max to cal3d format

Tags: animation, models, blender, 3d-meshes, skeletal-animation

There are quite a few questions on cal3d but they are old and don't apply anymore.

In Blender(must be 2.49a for python script to work!!!):

I have a scene with 7 meshes, 1 armature, 10 bones. I tried going to one mesh to simplify it but doesn't change anything. I found a small blend file that was used for cal3d and it exported just fine. So I tried to copy it's setup with no success.

EDIT*8/13/2012

In the last week here is what I have found so far.

I made the mesh in the newest blender(2.62?) and exported it to import it in the old one(2.49a). Did an animation in the old one because importing new blend files to old blenders, its just said it would lose keyframe data and all was good. And then you get the last problem of it not exporting meshes. BUT I found that meshes made in the old one export regardless. I can't find any that won't export. So if I used the old blender to remake my model I could get it to export :)

At this point I found a modified release of cal3d (because the most core model variable would not initiate as I made a really small test subject in old blender instead of remaking my big one which took 4 hours.) which fixes the morph objects and adds what cal3d left off with. Under their license they have to release the modification but it has no documentation so I have to figure it out on my own. Its mostly the same. But with this lib it came with a 3ds max exporter.

My question now is how do I transfer armature and mesh information from blender to 3ds max in order to export into cal3d format. Every time I try the models are see through and small and there are no bones. The formats I have tried to import are .3ds .obj(mesh only) and COLLADA. In all of them the mesh is invisible and no bones. It says the default texture is on so I should be able to see it. All the vertices are present I found a vertex highlighter so I can see those.

If any of this is confusing let me know so I can clear it up. Its late >.<=sleep.

Answer (score 1):

[blender2cal3d](https://github.com/alexeyd/blender2cal3d) worked for me in 2.49. Remember to make sure you select and export the skeleton first.

Comment: I've been using the same thing. Do I only need the pytocal.py or do I need the other python files that are in a folder. Everything export except the mesh. I also found a bunch more out since. read em in my edit.

Comment: i didn't spend too much time on it.. i made the switch to assimp.. but this should help you https://github.com/alexeyd/blender2cal3d/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have to give that a try. I'm currently have a bunch of things to try and I'm going down the list XD.